# Toggle Keyboard Viewer on Mac OS X programmatically

Tags: macos, cocoa, keyboard, viewer

I created a cocoa app which has a window with a text field to get user input, a small keyboard-icon button to bring up the keyboard viewer. When the user clicks OK or Cancel button  to finish, i want to hide the keyboard viewer. What I've done is as follows:

```
//action for keyboard-icon button
-(IBAction)input:(id)sender
{
    [self toggleKeyboard:YES];
}

//action for Cancel button
-(IBAction)cancel:(id)sender
{
    [self toggleKeyboard:NO];
    [NSApp abortModal];
    [[self window] orderOut: self];
}

//action for OK button
-(IBAction)ok:(id)sender
{
    [self toggleKeyboard:NO];
    [NSApp stopModal];
    [[self window] orderOut: self];
}


-(void)toggleKeyboard:(BOOL)show
{
    NSDictionary *property = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:(NSString*)kTISTypeKeyboardViewer
                                                  forKey:(NSString*)kTISPropertyInputSourceType];
    NSArray *sources = (NSArray*)TISCreateInputSourceList((CFDictionaryRef)property, false);

    TISInputSourceRef keyboardViewer = (TISInputSourceRef)[sources objectAtIndex:0];
    if (show == YES)
    {
        TISSelectInputSource(keyboardViewer);
    }
    else 
    {
        TISDeselectInputSource(keyboardViewer);
    }

    CFRelease((CFTypeRef)sources);

}
```

I can launch keyboard viewer successfully, but it cannot be hidden by TISDeselectInputSource  at all times.

Comment: The "Keyboard Viewer" you're displaying in MacOS is not meant to be used the same way as the pop-up keyboard in iOS, and I'm pretty sure it can not be easily dismissed programmatically.  If nobody else comes up with a better solution, I might research a bit into how to dismiss it via Apple Events or Apple Script.

Comment: Hi Michael, i just cannot find open source virtual keyboards on Mac OS or any documentation about how to implement it. I've tried applescript method(refer [this](http://patjack.co.uk/toggle-keyboard-viewer-in-snow-leopard-10-6/) ) using NSAppleScript class, but it doesn't work. Could you give out a truely working applescript here? or some suggestions on how to implement virtual keyboard in cocoa? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @leochou0729: Is there a particular reason you're trying to show a virtual keyboard?

Comment: I created a cross-platform NPAPI plugin using firebreath framework, which can pop up a modal dialog to get user credentials. In windows, user can directly input their passwords or choose soft keyboard as an additonal option for security reasons(against keyloggers for example). So I MUST implement the same thing on MAC OS. just consumer demand.

Comment: Can someone give out a very basic sample code about how to implement virtual keyboard in cocoa? I've been googling a lot and found no answer :(

Comment: Can anyboby give me some suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to programmatically hide the Keyboard Viewer. I made an AppleScript for my media center a little while ago that will toggle it. I'm not going to include the bit that shows it, partly because you've already figured that out, but mostly because the way I did it was to call some executable that I can't remember where I got it from.

Anyway, here's the AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Events"
    if exists (process "Keyboard Viewer") then
        click (process "Keyboard Viewer"'s window 1's buttons whose subrole is "AXCloseButton")
    end if
end tell
```

This uses Accessibility, so you need to have "Enable access for assistive devices" turned on in order for it to work.

Note this same thing can be accomplished in a Objective-C / C++ app using the Accessibility API, which you could use to avoid having to call into AppleScript in your app.

Comment: But the process of keyboard viewer is still running even after closing the window of the keyboard viewer. You need to quit it: *quit application "KeyboardViewer"*